# VS code-server starting service issue

Tags: code-server, visual-studio-code-server

I want to make code-server on my vps and when I'm starting service this error appears:

```
x code-server.service - code-server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/code-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-16 21:57:59 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 1300 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/code-server --host 127.0.0.1 --user-data-dir /var/lib/code-serve>
   Main PID: 1300 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 2ms

May 16 21:57:59 ip7 systemd[1]: code-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 16 21:57:59 ip7 systemd[1]: Stopped code-server.
May 16 21:57:59 ip7 systemd[1]: code-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 16 21:57:59 ip7 systemd[1]: code-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 16 21:57:59 ip7 systemd[1]: Failed to start code-server.
```

This is code-service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=code-server
After=nginx.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=PASSWORD=password
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/code-server --host 127.0.0.1 --user-data-dir /var/lib/code-server --auth password
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

I tried to search how to repair this

Comment: https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/1580

Comment: It also does't work